# Can I redefine which super class to extend in ByteBuddy?

Tags: java, byte-buddy

As the title reads, can I redefine the `extends` clause when redefining a class using ByteBuddy?

That is, redefining class `A` from `A extends B` to `A extends C` for example.

I've read the javadoc and it only suggests a `DynamicType.Builder.implement` mechanism which only accepts additional interfaces, but it's not for superclasses.

Is there someone tried this?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a rather difficult translation as this affects a significant portion of the class when it comes to super class access and super method calls.

You can register a `ClassVisitorWrapper` and change the property using ASM on the `ClassVisitor`'s visit method.